# Unmatched arrays extending in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I wrote a code but when i am trying to change the variable schedule(2,:) it gives error. Here's the code:

```
clc;clear;
a = [1 2 3 4];
N = 3;
c=[1:12];
schedule(1,:) = kron(a,ones(1,N));% repeat 4 days
schedule(2,:) = repmat([1 2 3],1,((numel(c)/length(a)))+1); % repeat time slots in each day %nums col rep
schedule(3,:) = randperm(c(1,end)); % randomize 12 courses
schedule
```

I need a way of matching lengths of schedule(2,:) with other rows. When length  of other rows is 20, schedule(2,:) does not build more than 20.

Comment: What do you mean with "it's not standard"? What length would you assume for `schedule(2,:)`? In matlab a vector does always have a size NxMxLx... depending on dimensions. Each element can only hold one value or object.

Comment: The arrays for each row in a matrix need to be the same in Matlab- if I get your question correctly.

Comment: You may want to read the [matlab fundamentals](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/matlab_prog.pdf) to begin with. Pretty good if you get troubles. You cannot expect Matlab to work the same as the language you are used to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
clc;clear;





day = [1 2 3 4];
n=length(day);
time=[1 2 3];
a=length(time);
schedule(1,:) = kron(day(1):n,ones(1,a));
schedule(2,:) = repmat(time,1,n);
schedule(3,:) = randperm(120,length(schedule(2,:)));

schedule
```

i have completed my code myself haha :) it is aflexible matrix and can accept any changes awithout errors